# C# - FluentValidation(11.4.0) - Generic type validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a FluentValidation class:

`public class ResourceDtoValidator<TResource> : AbstractValidator<ResourceDtoValidator<TResource>>`

The problem is the next:

`RuleFor(x => x.Resource)`

I have a TResource property in ResourceDtoValidator ( x.Resource is that prop ) which can be 3 different type.
Forexample: HumanResource, HardwareResource, OtherResource.

How can i set a rule for that?

Thanks for helping.

I tried to write an extension method, but it was very ugly and not worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a validation rule for the **Resource** property, you can make use of the **When** method provided by FluentValidation which allows you to conditionally apply a validation rule based on the value of another property like so:

```
public class ResourceDtoValidator<TResource> : AbstractValidator<ResourceDtoValidator<TResource>>
{
    public ResourceDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Resource)
            .When(x => x.Resource is HumanResource, () => 
            {
                // Set validation rules for HumanResource type
            })
            .When(x => x.Resource is HardwareResource, () => 
            {
                // Set validation rules for HardwareResource type
            })
            .When(x => x.Resource is OtherResource, () => 
            {
                // Set validation rules for OtherResource type
            });
    }
}
```

In each of the **When** methods, you can set the validation rules specific to each type of **Resource** using the FluentValidation API.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i find a better way.
I defined a common Interface for Resources and i used

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Resource)
 .SetInheritanceValidator(v =>
                {
                    v.Add<HumanResource>(new HumanResourceValidator());
                    v.Add<HardwareResource>(new HardwareResourceValidator());
                    v.Add<OtherResourc>(new OtherResourcValidator());
                });
```